# Why do I need to write number=int(input()) in this while loop again, when its already declared at the top of my code?

Tags: python

I have some python code below to find the maximum and minimum values from a given input, but I'm not sure why I need to include number=int(input()) again within the while loop. If I remove this line of code in the while loop, the program enters an infinite loop and I'm not sure why.

```
number = int(input())

min_value = number

max_value = number

while (number>0):
    
    if (number>max_value):
        max_value = number
    if (number<min_value):
        min_value = number
    number=int(input())
print(min_value, 'and', max_value)
```

Comment: You wrote it once at the top of your code, outside of any loop, so that means it will ask for input once. You want your program to ask for input multiple times.

Comment: Do you want to get input once or multiple times?

Comment: Think about the purpose/goal of your code. Why do you have a `while` loop for checking number? What condition do you want for the loop to end? If you don't get `input` for `number` again, then it does not get updated for the `while` condition.

Comment: `when its already declared`: That might be the source of your confusion. It's not a declaration, it's a function call and an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
user_input = input("Enter the numbers separated by a space ").split()

int_list = list(map(int, user_input))

print ("Max number:",max(int_list), "\nMin number:",min(int_list))`
```

Answer (score -2):

The code will ask for input multiple times as it does not make sense to find maximum and minimum if you have only one number. Also, it will help you to exit the while loop whenever a 0 is entered.